# Tried to delete Kali, now I am stuck at Grub rescue

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, youtube

I attempted to delete Kali using a YouTube video, now I am stuck at the grub rescue screen. I follow the command line

```
grub rescue >ls 
(hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
grub rescue> set
cmdpath=(hd0,gpt1)/EFI/KALI
prefix=(hd0,gpt6)/boot/grub
root=(hd0,gpt6)
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,gpt1)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt1)/boot/grub
grub rescue> insmod normal 
error: unknown filesystem.
```

I also do not have a boot disk or drive for windows or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your system uses UEFI firmware and `(hd0,gpt1)` (first partition on the disk) is your EFI System Partition (ESP). `(hd0,gpt6)` (6th partition) used to be your Kali partition, which seems to be now deleted. Now only the core image of GRUB is left, probably in `(hd0,gpt1)/EFI/KALI/grubx64.efi`.

`set prefix=(hd0,gpt1)/boot/grub` will only help if the first partition on your disk is the partition that contains the `/boot/grub` directory of the Linux installation. But the fact that your `prefix` and `root` already refer to `(hd0,gpt6)` suggests that that directory was actually on the 6th partition, which apparently no longer exists. Without the GRUB modules and configuration file on the 6th partition, GRUB won't work fully.

You might try `chainloader (hd0,gpt1)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` if you also have Windows installed. Or enter the BIOS settings and set "Windows Boot Manager" as your primary boot target if it exists.

Comment: It tells me that chainloader is an unknown command. I am stuck in grub purgatory.

Comment: I had to go through my bios and change the boot menu, but I have windows again. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Whether the `chainloader` command will work or not in that situation is determined by which modules are embedded into the GRUB core image - and that tends to vary between distributions.